# How can I create a button with html code to open Windows-Explorer?

Tags: html, xcode, internet-explorer, button, windows-explorer

I have a page with buttons that lead to various websites. One button should open a link in Windows Explorer. My code for web-links is:

```
               <input onclick="location.href='https://...';" type="button" value="Organisation" style="width: 150px; height: 50px; font-size: 15px;">&nbsp;
```

I tried this with a file path but it doesnt work and I cant find a solution on the internet. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where is the page you are talking about? Why the link has to be opened in Windows Explorer? Do you mean you want to open `href="file:///path/to/file"` ?

Comment: The page with the buttons is a website. The link should lead to a document or to a folder in Windows Explorer. If I just write file://path instead it doesnt work. :(

Comment: 3 slash not 2 `file:///`

Comment: I tried the same with the /// but it still doesnt work